# Visual Studio npcc64_60.dll trap?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I get the following  really interesting error: [image: Interesting error.]

Searching on google does not give me any direct answer. My setup is the following. 
I use Visual Studio 2013 professional. Fameworks in use: NVidea SDK, Qt, OpenCV. Everything is setup because the software was working. After windows update something went wrong.

Can somebody point me in any direction ... how can I find out the starting point of the error, I cant even debug?

Comment: First you have to find the nppc64_60.dll on your computer. Than let your application find it too.

Comment: There is none, I checked it. But I cant figure out who deppends on it.

Comment: loacte it, and add the folder to the PATH env var

Comment: how can you locate if its missing, I dont get your point ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occures because NVidea SDK 6.0 is missing. My problem was that the library was used by a prebuilt component.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Dependency Walker (depends.exe) tool to find out where this DLL dependency comes from. That should help to track the problem.

Comment: I give a try, if it works I accept as solution! Sounds promising!

Comment: It was not working. I have to mention that it's strange that I don't get any search result about this file in google ...

Comment: Yes, I noticed this too. You could not find the DLL in the entire dependency tree of the application? Did you check all levels? Are you aware that DLLs can require DLLs?